# Combining data contained in several lists

Tags: python

I am working on a personal project in python 3.6. I used pandas to import the data from an excel file in a dataframe and then I extracted data into several lists.

Now, I will give an example to illustrate exactly what I am trying to achieve.
So I have let's say 3 input lists a,b and c(I did insert the index and some  additional white spaces for in lists so it is easier to follow):

```
   0  1      2     3        4      5    6  

a=[1, 5,     6, [10,12,13], 1,   [5,3] ,7]

b=[3, [1,2], 3,  [5,6],   [1,3], [5,6], 9]

c=[1, 0 ,    4,  [1,2],     2  ,  8   , 9]
```

I am trying to combine the data in order to get all the combinations when in one of the lists there is a list containing multiple elements. So the output needs to be like this:

```
   0  1  2  3   4  5  6   7   8   9   10 11    12  13  14  15  16 17 18 19 20 21 22

a=[1, 5, 5, 6, 10,10,10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 12,   13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 1, 5, 5, 3, 3, 7]

b=[3, 1, 2, 3,  5, 5, 6,  6, 5,  5,  6,  6,    5,   5,  6,  6, 1, 3, 5, 6, 5, 6, 9]

c=[1, 0, 0, 4,  1, 2, 1,  2, 1,  2,  1,  2,    1,   2,  1,  2, 2, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9]
```

To make this more clear:

From the original lists if we look at index 1 elements: 
a[1]=5, b[1]=[1,2], c[1]=0. These got transformed to the following values on the 1 and 2 index positions: a[1:3]=[ 5, 5 ]; b[1:3]=[1, 2]; c[1:3]=[ 0, 0]

This needs to be applied also to index 3,  4, and 5 in the original input lists in order to obtain something similar to the example output above.

I want to be able to generalize this to more lists (a,b,c.....n). I have been able to do this for two lists, but in a totally not elegant, definitely not pythonic way. Also I think the code I wrote can't be generalized to more lists.

I am looking for some help, at least some pointers to some reading material that can help me achieve what I presented above.

Thank you!

Comment: Please show your code and explain which specific part(s) you are having difficulty with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.
Looks at each column, works out the combinations, then output the list:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy

a=[1, 5,     6, [10,12,13], 1,   [5,3] ,7]
b=[3, [1,2], 3,  [5,6],   [1,3], [5,6], 9]
c=[1, 0 ,    4,  [1,2],     2  ,  8   , 9]

df = pd.DataFrame([a,b,c])

final_df = pd.DataFrame()
i=0
for col in df.columns:
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(df[col])
    get_combo = []
    for idx, row in temp_df.iterrows():
        get_combo.append([row[i]])

    combo_list = [list(x) for x in numpy.array(numpy.meshgrid(*get_combo)).T.reshape(-1,len(get_combo))]
    temp_df_alpha = pd.DataFrame(combo_list).T
    i+=1   
    if len(final_df) == 0:
        final_df = temp_df_alpha
    else:
       final_df = pd.concat([final_df, temp_df_alpha], axis=1, sort=False) 


for idx, row in final_df.iterrows():
    print (row.tolist())
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 5, 5, 6, 10, 10, 12, 12, 13, 13, 10, 10, 12, 12, 13, 13, 1, 1, 5, 5, 3, 3, 7]
[3, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 1, 3, 5, 6, 5, 6, 9]
[1, 0, 0, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9]
```